# I get InterruptedException while sending data to kafka from multiple producers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to run kafka producer using the kafka-clients api. I have multiple producers running with separate threads and each trying to write data to kafka. The problem is I get an interrupted exception from kafka when I increase the number of threads running in parallel. For example, if I run 20 threads in parallel, it doesn't throw any exception but when I run it with 100 threads in parallel, I get the below exception:

> Exception in thread "pool-910-thread-1" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1154)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1128)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1107)
>       at com.t4e.kafka.producer.IEC104KafkaReadMessageProcessor.runProducer(IEC104KafkaReadMessageProcessor.java:45)
>       at com.t4e.iec104.connection.Iec60870ReadListener.writeToJsonFile(Iec60870ReadListener.java:707)
>       at com.t4e.iec104.connection.Iec60870ReadListener.newASdu(Iec60870ReadListener.java:75)
>       at org.openmuc.j60870.Connection$ConnectionReader$1.run(Connection.java:143)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1260)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1152)

Here's my producer code:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IEC104KafkaReadMessageProcessor.class);
    static KafkaProducerConfigReader kafkaConfig = new KafkaProducerConfigReader();
    static String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    /**
     * @param message
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws ExecutionException
     */
    public static synchronized RecordMetadata runProducer(String message) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Producer<Long, String> producer = ProducerCreator.createProducer();
        ProducerRecord<Long, String> record = new ProducerRecord<Long, String>(kafkaConfig.getTopicName(), message);
        try {
            RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
            logger.info(("Record sent with key " + " to partition " + metadata.partition() + " with offset "
                    + metadata.offset()));
            return metadata;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error("ExecutionException : Error in sending record to kafka");
            throw new ExecutionException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("InterruptedException : Error in sending record" + newLine);
            throw new InterruptedException();
        } finally {
            logger.info(" Closing Kafka producer ");
            producer.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may not be in this piece of code where you are creating a producer. Looking at the log you shared,

> Exception in thread **"pool-910-thread-1"** org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException

I can see that there are 910 thread pools active. Creating that many number of pools instead of creating threads keeping a single pool would probably be a better idea.
You might want to look at the place where you are creating the thread pools and control it.

I suspect a **thread leak** in your code would be causing this interrupt exception.